# vertical space after a list but only before a new paragraph

Tags: lists, paragraphs, enumitem, vertical-spacing, parskip

How to insert a `\parskip` after lists, but only before a new paragraph?

In the example below, the desired output would be no vertical space after the first list and vertical space after the second list:

[image]

What I get instead is no space between the second list and the third paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skip=\smallskipamount]{parskip}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{
  topsep=-\smallskipamount,
  partopsep=\smallskipamount,
  parsep=0pt
}
 
\begin{document}

A paragraph that contains a list
\begin{itemize}
\item item one
\item item two
\end{itemize}
within it.

A paragraph that ends with a list
\begin{itemize}
\item item one
\item item two
\end{itemize}

Another paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `topsep` is a bit of a misnomer: The parameter applies not only to the space *above* the list environment, but also to the space *below* it. By setting this parameter to a negative length number, you pretty much guarantee there will be hardly any whitespace between the list environment and whatever follows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this, but I'm not sure if it gives the wanted space in all cases. E.g. if a sectioning or another list follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=\smallskipamount]{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{
  topsep=-\smallskipamount,
  partopsep=\smallskipamount,
  parsep=0pt
}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/itemize/after}
  {%
   \AddToHookNext{para/before}
     {\if@endpe\else\vspace{\parskip}\fi}%
  }
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
\makeatletter A paragraph that contains a list 
\begin{itemize}
\item item one
\item item two
\end{itemize}
within it.

A paragraph that ends with a list
\begin{itemize}
\item item one
\item item two
\end{itemize}

Another paragraph.

\end{document}
```